# Objective-C FIFO queue

Tags: objective-c, queue

I want to implement a FIFO queue class having a simple thread-safe. I dont want to use any class (other than NSObject) from the standard Objective-C frameworks, it means i dont want to use NSMutableArray.

Can you se if my solution is correct? thank you!

```
#import <Foundation/NSObject.h>

@interface Queue : NSObject
{
    id _value;
    Queue *tail;
}
/* Puts an object at the end of the queue. The object is retained.  */
- (void) putObject: (id)object;

/* Gets an object from the beginning of the queue.  The object is
 * removed from the queue.  If there are no objects in the queue,
 * returns nil.  The object is autoreleased.
 */
- (id) getObject;
@end

@implementation Queue
- (id) init
{

    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc
{

    [super dealloc];
}

- (void) putObject: (id)object
{

    if(tail)
    {
        [tail putObject:object];
    }else{
        tail = [[Queue alloc]init];
        _object = object;
    }
}

- (id) getObject
{
    return _value;
}
@end
```

Comment: The Q is out of scope of SO.

Comment: After you read their [question guidelines](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), you might want to move this to Code Review.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you se if my solution is correct? thank you!

Have you tested it?

Some things for you to consider:

- A quick read suggests this is a "first in, only first out" design... (look at getting an object)
- Adding an object takes too long (O(N) vs. O(1))
- It would be better if you used ARC for memory management (your `[super dealloc]` indicates you are using MRR/MRC)

And listen to Josh Caswell in the comments, this isn't really the forum for these types of question.

HTH